# Is Scikit custom tokenizer used upon calling predict function?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, text-mining

Per below, the Scikit-learn documentation has a nice example of a custom tokenizer.  I am using this in conjunction with the pipeline feature.

My questions is, when I call predict on the trained classifier, will the text data go through the same custom tokenizer automatically?  Or do I have to explicitly run the input text through through the tokenizer before it is sent the classifier's predict function?

If the transformation happens automatically upon calling the predict function, is there a way to view the post-transformed text that gets predicted upon?

Thanks!

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize          
>>> from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer 
>>> class LemmaTokenizer(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
...     def __call__(self, doc):
...         return [self.wnl.lemmatize(t) for t in word_tokenize(doc)]
...
>>> vect = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=LemmaTokenizer())
```

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html